# Android Non-code drawing tool for initial game visualization

Tags: android

I'm just starting out in app development and have a board game concept that I would like to visualize before coding it.

Which free ware would you recommend that I use and then afterwards maybe even port assets and other resources to my Eclipse Android IDE?

The key thing for me right now is to have a tool I can use to make and see the game :-O

If it happens to generate simple java code,that'd be great ;-)

If it's a plugin editor for eclipse that'd be superb :-)

And lastly has anyone ever used Java Ascii Versatile Editor for this purpose?

BTW there's a fantastic eclipse free hand drawing resource called Sketch currently in development.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Google's AppInventor?

Comment: Thanks.I have always thought AppInventor is for educational purposes like lower grade shool sort of stuff...I guess I was mistaken,I will have a look at it and give you feedback.Thanks a mil.

Comment: Hey MarvinLabs, what a pleasant pleasant surprise!                                It is simple and concise and best of all I even get to see the source code.                                                          It just goes to show the adage 'never have contempt prior to investigation.'I guess one of the most important lessons which I have to remind myself always is that I should attempt new and or alternate things,methods,ways,etc

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean with the term "visualize"

If you are refering to graphics - maybe with some animations - than inkscape might be a good tool. It creates vector graphics as SVG (which allows scripting for simple animations).
SVG also has the advantage that you can render it easily to PNG at various resolutions.

Comment: Hey Christian,thank you, thank you, thank you.Inkscape is actually on my list;it is good to know I'm on the right track...I'd appreciate any extra advise for a newbie like me.By the way

Comment: By the way if it isn't too personal,have you ever got an Android game app published?                                                And what do you think of Unity as a beginner's starting point and would it eventually be possible to somehow port a game developed there to Android?

Comment: Hey Christian,Inkscape has just been great.Sorry for being a bit too personal...it is just all the excitement.